# jTidy html to xhtml returns empty file

Tags: java, xhtml, html-parsing, jtidy

I'm trying to create an xhtml file from an html file, but i'm facing an error.
During conversion i get the following error:

> line 1 column 1 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
>
> InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 2.0
>
> 1 warning, no errors were found!

my code is the following:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); //HTML parser and pretty printer. 
tidy.setXHTML(true); //true if tidy should output XHTML   
tidy.parse(fin, fout);
```

At the end i receive an empty file. What am i doing wrong?

Sincerely, Zoli

Answer (score 2):

Try to force the output like the following, and it will return the forced result.
**tidy.setForceOutput(true).**